# Why pinv answer not equal with svd method answer in Matlab？

Tags: matlab, matrix, svd, inverse

```
a = [1 2 3
     2 4 6
     3 6 9];
b = pinv(a);

[U,S,V] = svd(a); 
T = S;
T(find(S~=0)) = 1./S(find(S~=0));
svda = V * T' * U';
```

I find that the `pinv` method in Matlab uses the SVD decomposition to calculate pseudo-inverse, so I tried to solve the matrix `a`.

And as shown above, theoretically the `b` should be equal with `svda`, but the Matlab result said they are totally different. Why?

`b` is

```
0.00510204081632653 0.0102040816326531  0.0153061224489796
0.0102040816326531  0.0204081632653061  0.0306122448979592
0.0153061224489796  0.0306122448979592  0.0459183673469388
```

`svda` is

```
-2.25000000000000      -5.69876639328585e+15   3.79917759552390e+15
-2.14021397132170e+15   1.33712246709292e+16  -8.20074512351222e+15
 1.42680931421447e+15  -7.01456098285751e+15   4.20077088383351e+15
```

How does `pinv` get to its result?

**REASON:**

Thanks to Cris, I check my S, and it do have 2 very large number, and that is the source of this strange result.

S:

```
14.0000000000000    0                       0
0                   1.00758232556386e-15    0
0                   0                       5.23113446604828e-17
```

By pinv method and Cris method, this 2 latter numbers should set to 0 which I didnt do. So here is the reason。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pinv` doesn't just invert all the non-zero values of `S`, it also removes all the nearly zero values first. From the documentation:

> `pinv(A,TOL)` treats all singular values of `A` that are less than `TOL` as zero. By default, `TOL = max(size(A)) * eps(norm(A))`.

`pinv` more or less does this:

```matlab
[U,S,V] = svd(a); 
I = find(abs(S) > max(size(a)) * eps(norm(a)));
T = zeros(size(S));
T(I) = 1 ./ S(I);
svda = V * T.' * U';
```

On my machine, `isequal(svda,b)` is true, which is a bit of a coincidence because the operations we're doing here are not exactly the same as those done by `pinv`, and you could expect rounding errors to be different. You can see what `pinv` does exactly by typing `edit pinv` in MATLAB. It's a pretty short function.

---

Note that I used `T.'`, not `T'`. The former is the transpose, the latter is the complex conjugate transpose (Hermitian transpose). We're dealing with real-valued matrices here, so it doesn't make a difference in this case, but it's important to use the right operator.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think i get your point, it's because that I didn't set the number less than tol in S to 0, resulting in a power of ten error. So I check S, it do have 2 very large number, thank you so much!